# Transformations too slow in mapping

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I am having a mapping where my source is a view and a table with the source qualifier doing a join and has transformations like sorter, aggregator, router update strategy andfinally 2 target for insert and update to same table.

However while running, all the transformations are too  time consuming. While if i connect from source to target directly it works fast.

I tried doing sorting within source qualifier and it came out fast while when I did just Source-sorter-target, it is too slow in reading itself and not writing at all.

Can anyone help what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

If you could post the code, someone might be able to identify any obvious bottlenecks. Otherwise, any one transformation, or a single line within a transformation, could be responsible - the best answer you could hope for would be a generic answer about best practice, probably not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like caching problem. Check the log for information about recommended cache size, round it up and assign to sorter manually in session (mapping tab).
Source -> Sorter - Target works the following way:

1. Reads all source data and builds cache
2. Once all data is read, performs sorting.
3. Once all data is sorted, starts writing.

Therefore "slow reading" means it's delayed by cache file. Not writing at all is expected - how can you start writing prior to sorting?

Side notes:

- Sorting for writing in relational table makes hardly any sense.
- Sorting for aggregating makes no sense as well.
- As mentioned above, code would be useful.
- Some best practices can be found [here](http://powercenternotes.blogspot.com/2013/07/powercenter-best-practices.html).

Comment: Well, This issue is resolved temporariy when I added an index to staging table. Got to still work out a permanat solution. This is happening for huger table with 10 million+ data

Answer (score 0):

You could identify the bottle neck from the session log statistics. Then go through the Performance Tuning Guide avaialble in the PowerCenter help to remove the bottleneck.